# Who is Space Gary?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi

[Gary the Dog](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm9209500/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t79) is/was Carrie Fisher's French Bulldog. Before she passed, Gary would be seen pretty much everywhere with Carrie. In *The Last Jedi* Gary has an [uncredited role](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2527336/fullcredits) as Space Gary.

When watching the film I couldn't seem to remember seeing Gary at all so I imagine he was in the casino on Canto Bight as a background alien.

Who/What is Space Gary?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Space Gary is indeed an alien who appears in the casino on Canto Bight. This has been confirmed by *The Last Jedi* director Rian Johnson on twitter.

> **@FanthaTracks:**  *We want to know if you can confirm this cute little creature is #spacegary in #TheLastJedi*
>
> **@rianjohnson**:   YES! Wow, good eyes.
>
> <sub>[Twitter, @rianjohnson](https://twitter.com/rianjohnson/status/938314810290302977)</sub>

The above tweet seems to have been deleted, though it has been preserved by Fantha Tracks and they have an article about it.

> [Cosmic Book news](https://www.cosmicbooknews.com/rian-johnson-deletes-tweets) reported on the 23rd July that [The Last Jedi](https://www.starwars.com/films/star-wars-episode-viii-the-last-jedi) director Rian Johnson has deleted over 20,000 tweets from his twitter account.
>
> At Fantha Tracks we checked this out and can confirm that the tweet that confirmed Space Gary in [The Last Jedi](https://www.starwars.com/films/star-wars-episode-viii-the-last-jedi) has been deleted, among many others.
>
> [image: Image of the tweet]
>
> We are sorry that Rian has felt he had to delete his whole back catalogue of tweets and we are sure that when the time is right we will find out he reason behind it.
>
> <sub>[Fantha Tracks, Rian Johnson deletes over 20,000 tweets](http://www.fanthatracks.com/news/rian-johnson-deletes-over-20000-tweets/)</sub>

Gary's twitter account has also since tweeted stating the same.

> Yes! The Last Jedi director @rianjohnson has made it official. I’m in the new #StarWars movie! Look for me!
>
> <sub>[Twitter, @Gary_TheDog](https://twitter.com/Gary_TheDog/status/938564650790260736)</sub>

His character is the following.

[image: Space Gary]
<sub>Image taken from Gary the Dog's twitter</sub>

In the film's final cut, he appears in the background just before a gambler mistakes BB-8 for a slot machine:

[image: Space Gary seen in the film]

Comment: Huh. I'd previously heard that all footage with him got cut (the Casino scene formerly being longer). Good to know that was not true.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I think your original position is correct. Look at the bottom-left corner of the image—it says "Empire" so this is a publicity still.  I don't remember a shot like this in the film itself.

Comment: I found him in the film, though it's not a good image, so you may want to revert my edit.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Apparently he was cut from the final film according to my [related question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/177604/58193). However, a user has edited an image in from the film.

Comment: @Gaultheria If that image is from the final film you may want to look at answering [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/177604/58193). Be clear if it is from the final film or a deleted scene though.

Comment: Okay, I've posted an answer there.  Thanks.